# Localization i18next

Tags: javascript, i18next

please help me.

```
25   displayText: i18next.t("LearningProcess.MenuName"),
39   displayText: i18next.t("LearningProcess.Mark.MenuName"),
```

I do localization and use the framework i18next.
This part is supposed to display the word from the json package but it doesn't, it's just empty in place of the word and nothing changes when switching the language.

(A very strange situation, but when you change the code, any, and save the page, the desired text appears)

```
1 import i18next from "i18next";
2 import { RouteType } from "./config";
3 import SchoolOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/SchoolOutlined";
4 import HomePage from "../pages/Home/HomePage";
5 import LearningProcessLayout from "../pages/LearningProcess/LearningProcessLayout";
6 import LearningProcessIndex from "../pages/LearningProcess/LearningProcessIndex";
7 import GroupPage from "../pages/LearningProcess/GroupPage";
8 import MarkPage from "../pages/LearningProcess/MarkPage";
9
10
11 const learningProcessMenu = i18next.t("LearningProcess.MenuName")
12
13
14 const appRoutes: RouteType[] = [
15  {
16    index: true,
17    element: <HomePage />,
18    state: "home",
19  },
20  {
21    path: "/learning-process",
22    element: <LearningProcessLayout />,
23    state: "learningProcess",
24    sidebarProps: {
25      displayText: i18next.t("LearningProcess.MenuName"),
26      icon: <SchoolOutlinedIcon />,
27    },
28    child: [
29      {
30        index: true,
31        element: <LearningProcessIndex />,
32        state: "learningProcess.index",
33      },
34      {
35        path: "/learning-process/mark",
36        element: <MarkPage />,
37        state: "learningProcess.mark",
38        sidebarProps: {
39          displayText: i18next.t("LearningProcess.Mark.MenuName"),
40        },
41      },
42      {
43        path: "/learning-process/group",
44        element: <GroupPage />,
45        state: "learningProcess.group",
46        sidebarProps: {
47          displayText: "Group",
48        },
49      },
50    ],
51  },
52 ];
53
54
55 export default appRoutes;
```

Tried with a variable, but nothing changed.